# How do I separate multiple items within a div class into separate lists?

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website using Selenium. The element on the site is formatted in a way where it has 3 categories worth of information I want to split up. The following is the code when I inspect element on my browser for what I am trying to scrape.

```
<div class="break-text ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="category.dataType == &quot;breakText&quot;">
Pinson, AL
<br>
Pinson Valley
</div>
```

This format has: 
"City", "State" 
.
 "High School" 
.

"Pinson", "AL" 
.
"Pinson Valley" 
.

respectively. How do I differentiate these lists when scraping the data?

```
city = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('break-text')
state = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('break-text')
highschool = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('break-text')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
data= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="break-text ng-binding ng-scope"]')
for d in data:
    city = d.text.split('\n')[0].split(',')[0]
    state = d.text.split('\n')[0].split(',')[1]
    highschool = d.text.split('\n')[1]
    print(city)
    print(state.strip())
    print(highschool)
```

Output:

```
Pinson
AL
Pinson Valley
```